# NodeJS passing parameter from HTML form

Tags: html, node.js, forms, express, post

I am trying to pass parameter from HTML form to NodeJS router. Routing works as expected but i get undefined for parameter value.

I have done it in a past with parameter being a value of input field. However, this time I am trying to do without fields and send parameter as part of action statement.

```
<form id="form_sidebar" action="/users/navigation?user_id=UserID" method="POST"> 
  <button id = "btn_button" type='submit'>Button</button>
</form>
```

on router side:

```
router.post('/navigation', (req, res) => {
  var fname =  req.body['user_id']
  console.log(fname)
})
```

I was expecting to get UserID printed in the console. But getting undefined.

Any input will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simply you are not accessing the right part of the request since you are passing user_id as query parameter, not inside the request body, so Express seralizes an object with the query parameters.
Try to access the parameter in this way:

```
router.post('/navigation', (req, res) => {
    var fname = req.query.user_id
    console.log(fname)
})
```